# Is it possible to output evaluated value using Template Meta Programming during compile time in C++?

Tags: c++, compilation

Buddies, 
I came cross a question during scientific research, Is it possible to output the evaluated value during compile time? It is sure that compiler evaluates expression during compile time, the point is how could we output the evaluated value during compiling? One method is to force error but seems not very elegant. If I wanna use TMP, is it possible to do?   Thanks.

Comment: You force a compiler error that shows the value somehow, usualy as a template parameter.

Comment: Can you show some sample, what exactly you want to see? The standard way to do this is to read Assembly code generated by compiler.

Comment: please show which evaluated you want to output in a piece of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to see the value of an integral constant expression, an easy way to see the value for debugging purposes is to create an error with that value. For example:

```
template <int> struct constexpr_debugger;

int main() {
    const int i0(4), i1(17);
    constexpr_debugger<i0 + i1> debug;
}
```

When I compile this code I get the message

```
constexpr_debugger.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
constexpr_debugger.cpp:5:37:error: aggregate ‘constexpr_debugger<21> debug’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined
         constexpr_debugger<i0 + i1> debug;
                                     ^
```

If you are interested in the values but still want to get the code to compile, the best approach I'm aware of is to create a warning message based, e.g., on an unused variable. Since warnings are never required by the standard, it depends a bit on the compiler and the flags used if warnings are shown. Giving it a test with [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and [clang](http://clang.llvm.org) shows that the compilers unfortunately don't show the value of the template parameter if the above class template is simply defined. The following code shows [currently] that compilers differ in what they report in their diagnostics:

```
template <int>
void constexpr_debugger()
{
    int debug;
}

int main() {
    const int i0(4), i1(17);
    constexpr_debugger<i0 + i1>();
}
```

gcc mentions the function including its template parameter and, hence, the desired value when warning about `debug` not being used. clang warns about `debug`, too, but doesn't mention the template instantiation where the problem happens. You'll need something of that form which works with the compiler you are using (possibly it needs to be tailored to the compiler version you are using).

Answer (score 1):

Since C++11, `constexpr` can be used to enable that expression be evaluated at compile time

Example :

```
constexpr int sqr(int x)
{
return x*x;
}

int a[sqr(4)]; //Compiles with C++11 and a has 16 elements.
```

For displaying an evaluated expression use template meta-programming

```
template<unsigned int n>
struct dummy ;

int main() {
        char<dummy1<dummy<1 + 55-2>::dummy2>()); //Obliviously wrong
        return 0;
}
```

Error from compiler:

`error: incomplete type 'dummy<54u>' used in nested name specifier`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like using compile errors or warnings, you can put type information into symbols in the object file. The following program will do that for a compile time list.

```
// Just define the types we need to construct lists.
template <typename Head, typename Tail> struct Cons {};
struct Nil {};

// This is what you want to output.
using MyOutput = Cons<int, Cons<float, Cons<char, Nil>>>;

// Template function declaration.
template <typename TheOutput>
void MyOutputFunc () {}

// Explicitly instantiate the template function with the desired output.
template void MyOutputFunc<MyOutput> ();
```

Retrieving the output will be compiler and perhaps OS-specific. The following demonstrates this for g++ on Linux.

```
$ g++ -c -std=c++11 a.cpp
$ nm a.o | grep MyOutputFunc
0000000000000000 W _Z12MyOutputFuncI4ConsIiS0_IfS0_Ic3NilEEEEvv
$ nm a.o | grep MyOutputFunc | cut -d ' ' -f3 | c++filt
void MyOutputFunc<Cons<int, Cons<float, Cons<char, Nil> > > >()
```

You can output integers by wrapping them in a type like this:

```
template <typename T, T value>
struct WrapValue {};

using MyOutput = WrapValue<int, 15>;
```

This is more useful for retrieving various supporting information as opposed to debugging. For example, my use case for this method was related to configuration options for some microcontroller software, and the compile time output is how the template program mapped the configuration options to EEPROM memory.